# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: datos.paises.forEach is not a function en AngularJS

Tags: angular, typescript, aplicación-web

estoy empezando a programar y me encuentro un poco verde, os explico mi problema. Me encuentro ante la situación en la que hago una petición a una restAPI que me devuelve un json con los datos que necesito, pero ahora, una vez que tengo las datos almacenados en una variable, no se acceder a ellos, he estado mirando en Internet y lo que he encontrado es que accedo mediante puntos corchetes y demás, pero me da un error con el forEach y no se resolverlo, por mas vueltas que le he dado a Internet no encuentro nada, os dejo el código completo por aquí y a ver si me podéis ayudar...

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import {GraficaArduinoService} from '../../../Services/pagina-inicio/grafica-arduino/grafica-arduino.service';
import { subscribeOn } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { RouterLinkWithHref } from '@angular/router';




declare var require: any;
let Boost = require('highcharts/modules/boost');
let noData = require('highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display');
let More = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');

Boost(Highcharts);
noData(Highcharts);
More(Highcharts);
noData(Highcharts);

@Component({
    selector: 'app-grafica-historicos',
    templateUrl: './grafica-historicos.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./grafica-historicos.component.scss']
  })
export class GraficaHistoricosComponent implements OnInit {
  public options : any = {
      chart: {
          type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Column chart with negative values'
      },
      xAxis: {
          categories: [] //nombre de los contaminantes
      },
      credits: {
          enabled: false
      },
      series: [] //nombre(name) del pais y valores(data) de los contaminantes
  }
  constructor(private _arduino: GraficaArduinoService) { }
  ngOnInit(){

   this._arduino.ObtenerDatos().toPromise().then(
     datos => {
      var pais:Array<string>
      var contaminantes:Array<string>
      var valContaminantes:Array<string>
      //MI GRAN PROBLEMA 
      datos["paises"].forEach(element => {
        console.log(element) 

      });
      }      
    )
  }
}
```

También os dejo un el codigo de error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: datos.paises.forEach is not a function
TypeError: datos.paises.forEach is not a function
```

Si necesitáis que os aclare algo que no entendáis nada mas tenéis que comentármelo.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: puedes hacer el log de la variables `datos` que te devuelve la api?

Comment: Aqui te dejo el enlace de la imagen, que aqui no puedo meterla y el log es largo para meterlo aqui: 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QikmaURMxwGKnVKZce1edaBgZKdoUJcm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: bueno `datos['paises']` no es un array es un objeto que tiene propiedades que son los nombres de los paises. Por lo tanto para acceder al array tienes que hacerlo asi `datos['paises'].spain.forEach`.

Comment: Perfecto problema solucionado, muchas gracias !!!

Comment: como puedo hacerte una valoracion??

Comment: jajaja pues lo pongo como respuesta y la acepta.

Comment: ah vale jajaja soy nuevo y no se como va, gracias otra vez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datos` es un objeto que contiene una propiedad que es `paises` que también es un objeto.

Por lo tanto, para acceder al array de datos de cada país debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
datos['paises'].spain.forEach // datos.paises.spain.forEach son equivalentes
```